# Deny SCHEMA DELETE in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
 CREATE LOGIN TestLogin WITH password='abc';

 -- Now add user to database
 USE TestDB;
 CREATE USER TestUser FOR LOGIN TestLogin;
 GO

 use [TestDB]
 GO
 DENY SCHEMA DELETE TO [TestUser]
 GO
```

I was doing something like this, but this doesn't seem to work. I want to DENY SCHEMA DELETE on all Schemas for TestUser. What would be a way to do that?

Comment: Use ssms.  Start by right clicking on testUser and selecting properties.

Comment: @DanBracuk I don't see a properties option by right clicking on the user. Only see New User, Script User As, Report, Rename, Delete and Refresh.

Comment: Using `DENY` is a bad idea in general, but especially for something like this, where T-SQL has no blanket right that covers it (denying delete on all existing schemas will not protect new ones, for example). Permission to delete any schema is included only in the `ALTER ANY SCHEMA` right on the database. Consider not putting the user in any roles where that permission is included (like `db_ddladmin`) but creating custom roles that only include the necessary permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You got it wrong. Rather it should be.

```
DENY DELETE ON SCHEMA :: schema_name TO [TestUser]
```

See [DENY Schema Permissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176128.aspx) for more information on the same. Actual syntax is:

```
DENY permission  [ ,...n ] } ON SCHEMA :: schema_name  
    TO database_principal [ ,...n ]   
    [ CASCADE ]  
        [ AS denying_principal ]
```

Comment: Yes, but I would then have to do this for all the Schemas. I don't want to do that as I want to DENY DELETE on all the schemas and not an individual one.

Comment: @hasanqureshi, that you will have to write it probably cause per my understanding you can's directly deny permission for all schemas in single go like that.

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage some dynamic sql for this.

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = ''

select @SQL = @SQL + 'DENY DELETE ON SCHEMA :: ' + name + ' TO [TestUser];'
from sys.schemas
where name not like 'db[_]%'

exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: Could you explain what the last line `exec sp_execute @SQL` is suppose to do? When I execute the code snippet you provided I get "Procedure expects parameter '@handle' of type 'int'." Thanks!

Comment: Oops. That should be sp_executesql. I will update this right now.